# Solution to $\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{df}{d r}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I know that $f(r)=aln(r)+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants is a solution of $$\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{d f}{dr}=0$$

are there any other solutions to this, would appreciate it if someone were to list a few down.

Comment: This is a general solution with $2$ constants of integration. The equation is of order $2$. So, there is no other solutions

Comment: @Yuriy S . Thanks!, very helpful.

Comment: You are confusing me with your partial derivatives. If $f$ is not only a function of $r$ then you have to introduce the other variables as arguments for your constants, which are functions in this case.

Comment: @Rayman, this is ODE then, not PDE, so it would make sense to edit the tag as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is $r^2f''(r)+r f' (r)=0$ which is Cauchy-Euler homogeneous equation. Put $r=e^z$ then $f'(r)= \frac{df}{dz}$$\frac{dz}{dr}$ gives $rf'(r)=\frac{df}{dz}$. Similarly, $r^2f''(r)=\frac{d^2f}{dz^2}-\frac{df}{dz}$.

- This reduces the given equation into $(D^2-D+D)f=0$ where $D=\frac{d}{dz}$ thereby giving $f(z)=a+bz$ as its solution. Substituting back $z=In(r)$, you will get the required result $f(r)=a+bIn(r)$

Comment: You should change "In" to "ln" but otherwise this is really great!

Answer (score 0):

$$y'=u\implies u_r+\frac{1}{r}u=0\implies \frac{du}{u}=-\frac{1}{r}dr\implies \ln u=-c\,\ln r=c_1\,\ln r\implies u=c_1r$$
$$y'=c_1\,r\implies y=c_1r^2+c_2$$
$$\frac{\partial^2{y}}{\partial{r^2}}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{r}}=2c_1=0\implies y=c_2$$

Answer (score 0):

With $g(r):=f'(r)$, the equation is of the first order and separable

$$\frac{g'(r)}{g(r)}=-\frac1r.$$

It has the general solution

$$\ln(|g(r)|)=-\ln(|r|)+C$$ or

$$f'(r)=g(r)=\frac Cr.$$ (The absolute values can be "absorbed" by the sign of $C$.)

Then integrating,

$$f(r)=C\ln(|r|)+C'.$$